# Can you give the button content as a parameter with a RelayCommand?

Tags: relaycommand

I have a method that changes the color of some textblocks, can you give the content as a parameter (string) with a RelayCommand?

```
 <Button Command="{Binding ColorCommand}"
                Content="Red"
                x:Name="Red"/>

 <Button Command="{Binding ColorCommand}"
                Content="Green"
                x:Name="Green"/>

 public void getColorForeground(string color)
    {
        if (color == "Red")
        {
            RedBackGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else if (color == "Green")
        {
            RedBackGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }

 public RelayCommand ColorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand>(() =>
            {
                getColorForeground(**NEED PARAMETER**);                
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `CommandParameter` property to pass a object/value to your command:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ColorCommand}" CommandParameter="Red"
                Content="Red"
                x:Name="Red"/>

 public RelayCommand ColorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand>((color) =>
            {
                getColorForeground(color);                
            });
        }
    }
```